# Caching in an excel document level customization in vsto

Tags: visual-studio, caching, vsto, excel-2007

I have a document level customization in excel that is used to calculate and save quoting data. Basically each sheet is a quote with specific cells containing QuoteNo, Description, Totals etc.

I want to be able to extract this data into a list of POCO objects that is then cached as a property in the ThisWorksheet class.

I get the error

> The Cached attribute on the following member is in error because the
>   member is not public, static, read-only, or is a parameterized or
>   indexer property

I believe that this is because a list has an indexer property.

So how can I store this type of data in the cache?

Answer (score 0):

OK, not my preferred solution but it solves the problem.

I add a method to the class that inherits from list that creates xml with the relevant data. The BeforeSave event is used to add (or update) this xml to the customXmlParts. Other documents can then access this and de-serilaise it.

Clunky but it works, does anyone have anything more elegant?